# potentially color-blind person: how to choose colors for a graph

Tags: color-scheme, color-perception, color-blindness

I have a chart with 5 curves (curves 1-5). A person told me that colors 1 vs. 2 as well as colors 3 vs. 5 are difficult to distinguish. While I can understand that 3 and 5 are somewhat similar, the 1 and 2 are completely different in my view. I do not know, maybe this person color-blind. But I need to make the graph so that he will be able to distinguish the colors. My problem is that I have only 7 colors in total (additional two colors are 6 and 7). I did not use the yellow (6) originally because it is too faint in my view. The cyan (7) also is similar to blue.

How you would suggest me to choose the colors? The proximate curves should clearly have the most distinguishable colors.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Also, a similar question you can reference here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99732/how-can-i-find-a-color-scheme-that-is-appropriate-for-color-blind-persons

Answer (score 2):

Try using a tool such as [Color Oracle](http://colororacle.org/) or [Color Blindness Simulator](https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/) - the tool used to generate images. They will help you get an idea of how those colors may appear to someone who is color blind. Depending on the type of color blindness, 1 & 3 as well as 3 & 5 are hard to distinguish. If possible experiment with other color schemes to determine the best fit for usage. Otherwise based on the comparison diagram of common types of color blindness 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6 may work. However it sounds like the person you are testing could be color blind in which case they may have Tritanopia from the sounds of it (1 & 2 as well 3 & 5 are hard to distinguish for them).

[image: different types of color blindness]